# how to update an existing Visual Studio 2012 SQL Server Database project from a database?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-project

I'm trying to use VS 2012 SQL Server Database project for versioning control of our database schema. However, our database schema is being updated by another team/tool, instead of through the Database project. Whenever it's updated, I have to manually update the Database project files - very tedious and error-pron. I'm wondering if there is a way to auto refresh all the schema changes from the updated database (just like the EF UI design tool which has a 'Update model from database' menu)?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using Schema Compare to compare & update the schema changes. Learn more:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193250(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thank you! I'm aware of this schema compare tool and used it to update databases but never thought about using it to update the project!

Comment: You can save those schema comparisons within the project for future use as well. I would caution against importing everything. You still want to review the changes you're about to import.

Answer (score 0):

With the disclaimer that it's still a 'beta' feature (for now), you can now use [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/) to link your database with a database project. This integrates into SQL Server Management Studio. This means that you will get little blue indicators overlaid on the Object Explorer each time a change gets made to the database that isn't synced to your project. It doesn't matter where the change gets made, be it in SSMS or otherwise.

There's a 28-day trial, so we'd encourage you to try it and let us (Red Gate) know if you come across any issues.